# What is the easiest way to detect the state change of a complex object in Reactjs

Tags: javascript, reactjs, object, state, onreadystatechange

**I have a complex object as follows**

```
const myObject = { 
                 title:"main title",
                 row:[
                       {rowTitle:"t1",index:1},
                       {rowTitle:"t2",index:2}
                 ],
                 column:[
                          {columnTitle:"c1",index:1},
                          {columnTitle:"c2",index:2},
                 ]
}
```

I need to detect if the properties change or not.

```
isObjectUpdated(myObject){
  // return true/false
}
```

Comment: What's the reason why you want to detect this? React is primarily declarative, not imperative, so generally your logic should be based on your data, not whether or not it updates.

Comment: If it's a state object, it doesn't matter how complex it is, react will rerender if it is changed with setState

Comment: I want to send an update request if the object is changed from the previous state

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the case that you want the component / screen to be remounted if this object changes, you can use the `useState()` hook to achieve this behavior.